# Alert not showing when using load() method on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('#rafale').load(function (){    
    alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="rafale" src="https://signup.na.leagueoflegends.com/theme/signup_new_theme/img/logo-lol.png" alt="Rafale Jet" >
```

The above code is for showing an `alert` box after loading the image but it is not showing. Instead it's giving an error:

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a> function(…)

Comment: can you rewrite the question ? It's unclear

Comment: I rewrote the code.

Comment: thanks for the remarks, then why is that alert not loading? No , only the code I displayed is executed.

Comment: Is your image loading properly?, What happens if you change .load to click function? @RK

Comment: this should work `$('#rafale').load("url #div",function(){});` to load url into div

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer OP is attempting to hook to the `load` event, not load data in to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the amendment to the `load()` method in jQuery v3.x. It no longer creates a `load` event handler, but instead attempts to make an AJAX request to load content in to the selected element - hence the error is caused by the lack of a parameter.

To do what you require, use `on('load', fn)` instead. Try this:

```js
$('#rafale').on('load', function(){      
    alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="rafale" src="https://i.imgur.com/F5iJY.jpg" alt="Rafale Jet" >
```

Note that I changed the image source to  a valid location so that the event fires correctly. You would need to hook to the `error` event to capture `404` and other response codes.

Answer (score 1):

The load() method was deprecated[ one that has been outdated] in jQuery version 1.8 and removed in version 3.0.

```js
$('#rafale').on('load', function (){      
    alert('Test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<img id="rafale" src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/607/country-and-mobile-redirect-for-wordpress-dwpsxm-clipart.jpg" alt="" />
<p><b>Note:</b> Depending on the browser, the load event may not trigger if the image is cached.</p>
</body>
```